# Flutter not building app without error at all

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

My Flutter project was working just fine. I lost my Internet connection for a bit and when it came back I got a pop up talking about an Android Configuration found for the project, I clicked Add, then it started showing me two Device slots on the Upper tab where it shows what devices are connected.

Now if I need to run my app on my device, Flutter simply tries to run the project, then stops without any output in the Run Tab of Android Studio. This is really giving me a headache... I wish it gave an error or something. Someone please help me so i can resume development.

[image: Note the Emptry Run Log, it tries to run the app, signified by the play icon gerying out but goes back to green after a couple seconds]

Comment: Try running `flutter run -v` from the console.

Comment: tried it, still not working. Even my Native android apps are behaving the same way.

Comment: Did you try running `flutter clean`? Also you can try deleting the .idea directory (That is the generated Android Studio's project configuration). After deleting that, open the project from the Android Studio Open dialog.

Answer (score 0):

if you have not changed anything in the android directory the easiest thing to do is to delete it, then run in the terminal

`flutter create .`

if you have changed a lot of things in the android you can copy your changes and do the same or can go an revert the gradle configurations manually.

Comment: Tried this but it's still not working. The error is persistent across all my projects even new ones. Quick Question, is an android SDK required to run my Flutter apps?

Comment: maybe you need to reinstall the android environment (not sure if it'll help)